# Change uitextField placeHolder from UIButton action

Tags: arrays, swift, uibutton, uitextfield, uitextfielddelegate

I have a button action that checks if two uitextfield.text values are empty, meaning the user didn't enter anything, if that's the case, then we change the placeHolder text.

Code Snippet:

```
    let qArr1 = ["sample1", "sample2", "sample3"]
    let qArr2 = ["sample4", "sample5", "sample6"]
    
    var indexA = Int.random(in: 0..<qArr1.count)
    var indexB = Int.random(in: 0..<qArr2.count)
    
    objc
    func submit(_ sender: UIButton) {
       if textFieldA.text.isEmpty || textField2.text.isEmpty {
       // present an alert to the user
       textFieldA.placeHolder = qArr1[indexA]
       textFieldB.placeHolder = qArr2[indexB]
     } 
     // perform actions if textFields have entered values
}
```

I am getting the placeHolder text randomly from an array of strings. So each time you have empty textFields, the placeHolder should update with the new random selected string from array.

Problems the placeHolder text is not updating in the respective textFields.

Im sure Im missing a simple step.

Comment: I just tried it in a test project and it works fine. You're going to have to provide the full code for a view controller, or maybe even a link to a Github repo with a minimum application that shows the problem you describe. (Have you set a breakpoint on your submit function and made sure it's being called? How were you able to connect the button action to that function without the `@IBAction` tag?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I have run your code there are multiple errors, Now I have update your code as follows:-**

```
 let qArr1 = ["sample1", "sample2", "sample3"]
 let qArr2 = ["sample4", "sample5", "sample6"]

 var indexA = Int()
 var indexB = Int()


@IBAction func submit(_ sender: UIButton) {

   self.indexA = Int.random(in: 0..<qArr1.count)
   self.indexB = Int.random(in: 0..<qArr2.count)

   if textFieldA.text!.isEmpty || textField2.text!.isEmpty {
        textFieldA.placeholder = qArr1[indexA]
        textFieldB.placeholder = qArr2[indexB]
    } 
   // perform actions if textFields have entered values
}
```